# ElasticSearch Cumulate multi_match and must_not query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently matching logs containing "_single", with this query working this far ..

`{"size":9999,"_source":["@timestamp","message"],"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"2022-06-01T07:54:45.00Z","lte":"2022-06-30T07:54:45.00Z"}}},{"multi_match":{"fields":["message"],"query":"_single_"}}]}}}`

I wanna exclude then logs containing these values :

`set_by_lua , buffered , forbidden , 403 , 302`

I've tried adding that statement, either in filter or query

`{"must_not":{"message":{"values":[" set_by_lua "," buffered "," forbidden "," 403 "," 302 "]}}}`

But none of them are accepted ..

`[1:248] [bool] failed to parse field [must_not] or [1:237] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]`

It has been days since I'm struggling to get it working ..

Thanks in advance for any clue, advice, notice, comment, enlightenment :)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to add the `must_not` clause outside the `filter` clause. You can refer to [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) documentation, to know more about its structure and usage.

Modify your query as :

```
{
    "size": 9999,
    "_source": [
        "@timestamp",
        "message"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2022-06-01T07:54:45.00Z",
                            "lte": "2022-06-30T07:54:45.00Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": [
                            "message"
                        ],
                        "query": "_single_"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": {
                "message": {
                    "values": [
                        " set_by_lua ",
                        " buffered ",
                        " forbidden ",
                        " 403 ",
                        " 302 "
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jack did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ;-)